# How to find if pointerMove in ionic range component was stopped?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-components

I have an ionic range component in my page and I call a method on pointerMove event. I stop that method on pointerUp. But the problem is that if a user move the range slider and then stop moving the slider but doesn’t take his finger up the stop method never call and my app is not correctly working.
I want to know if there is a way to find out when user stop moving his finger.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two commonly used listeners: ionBlur - gives you last value after the drag, ionChange - emits all values. Try using ionBlur for your case:

```
<ion-range (ionChange)=“sliderChanged()” (ionBlur)=“sliderLastChange()”>
```